# Arch Gnome mouse issues

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome, mouse, libinput

I just finished a nice, clean and new Arch install on my laptop yesterday and went for gnome as my desktop.
But as I set it up at work today, in ran into some heavy issues.
It looks like gnome went away from synaptics and now uses libinput instead.

So here are my issues:

- There are no seperate settings for mouse and touchpad in the
  settings. Changing the thouchpad settings works just fine for the
  touchpad, but it doesn't affect the mouse whatsoever (in particular:
  the scrolling direction).
- Changing the button map via xinput set-button-map {device-id} 1 2 3
  5 4 6 7 8 9 works for some applications, but im still stuck with
  "natural scrolling" in programs I don't want natural scrolling in
  (terminal, text edit etc.).
- My dconf doesn't have a touchpad section at
  /org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals and the mouse section only
  got the entries "double-click", "drag-threshold" and
  "locate-pointer" no settings for scrolling direction, mouse speed or
  acceleration in here as well.
- The "Keyboards and Mouse" Section in the gnome tweak tool doesn't
  provide any of those settings as well.

So what to do now? Going back to synaptics doesn't seem like a viable option, as gnome want's to abolish it completely. 
Is there anything else I'm missing?